# dual boot encrypted ubuntu with Windows 10 separate disks

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

I have two hard disks (SSD) with Win 10 on one.

I did have ubuntu 16.04 on the second (fully encrypted LVM) but after a Windows update, I no longer have access to the grub loader.

Ideally I would like to simply create another OS in Windows boot manager and point it to the Linux loader.

I may try installing ubuntu (have to boot to CD using UEFI) alongside, but since I have an existing encrypted partition, I am hoping I can simply install there (without needing to go through all the hassle with cryptsetup/pvcreate/vgcreate/lvcreate which was *way* too painful...)

Thoughts? Suggestions? Is it possible to modify where the Windows manager points?(I can copy an existing boot option there but I don't know how to edit it to point to where grub exists)
Thanks!
Jim

Comment: Think twice, why you need LVM and encryption? IMO most of the users doesn't need any of them.

Comment: If running Windows, I have to agree with pa4080. Bot can you directly boot from UEFI boot menu? Often f10 or 12? What brand/model system? Windows updates often change some settings like making it first in boot order (grub also does this) and turning on fast start up even if previously off. Grub only boots working Windows, so if Windows has hibernation/fast start on, or needs chkdsk, you have to directly boot from UEFI. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I cannot boot to my existing ubuntu image at all. I can boot from another media (USB, CD, etc.) but I cannot boot from the second hard disk. I know I could run an unencrypted system or simply encrypt my home directory. I want to encrypt the entire system. It is a Dell 7520 with two SSD drives. I can see both drives from either Windows or booting from a USB. I can install alongside Windows and use grub as the overall boot manager - but I was hoping to find someone who knows about editing the details of the Windows manager to point it at the second disk (where grub sits)